# Как при составлении вопроса выделить C# код?

Tags: поддержка, редактор, markdown

Добавьте идентификатор языка для включения подсветки синтаксиса в коде.

[image: Добавьте идентификатор языка...]

Какой он для Шарпа? Sharp? Не всегда сразу срабатывает

Comment: Подсветка делается банальным добавлением 4-х пробелов перед текстом (если пишете в студии, то это 1 tab), в редакторе на SO кстати тоже есть кнопка "Фрагмент кода"). По поводу самих идентификаторов - скорей всего `csharp`, а судя по [этой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) информации, так и вовсе можно писать тэг (`c#`).

Comment: По инфе из ссылки код должен быть cs

Comment: Ну как видите, вариантов [уйма](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSHye.png). Но честно, за все время, что я тут - очень редко использовался синтаксис, который вы описываете, обычно достаточно просто вставить правильно отформатированный код (с 4-мя пробелами в начале) и сайт его определит сам.

Comment: Туда можно все что угодно вписать, только что попробовал. Похоже, дело в метке...

Comment: Да, написано что `cs` - а что, не работает?

Comment: @Qwertiy Работает. Там и абракадабра работает. и cs можно и AbirValg и kjlsdfh...  Дело еще и в метке.

Comment: Если пишите на языке метки вопроса, то ничего добавлять не надо, и код лучше отделять отступом из четырёх пробелов, а не тройными апострофами. Если же, в одном вопросе/ответе надо смешать несколько ЯП и хочется, чтоб их подсветило правильнее, то да, не помешает знать\найти правильное заклинание.

Answer (score 4):

Подсветка С# включается указанием идентификатора `cs` или `c#`. Но делать этого не нужно, так как:

1. Это не приводит к заметному улучшению.
2. При установке метки C# подсветка включается автоматически

Обычно не стоит явно указывать язык подсветки синтаксиса, кроме некоторых особых случаев. Например, когда нужно показать кусок XML, а с подсветкой по умолчанию он выглядит ужасно. В этом случае можно указать явно идентификатор xml. В остальных случаях, default вполне справляется.

**Обновление** (2020-09-25): в связи с [переходом на highlight.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/) улучшилось как качество подсветки для C# (в плане обнаружения ключевых слов), так и качество автоопределения языка. Суть, впрочем, не сильно изменилась, явно указывать язык для C# так же нет необходимости.

Comment: Для vbscript тоже надо указывать.